# Keychain not the same for TestFlight vs App store build?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keychain

Is it normal that TestFlight uses a different keychain then the app store build?

I have added my login-credentials in my keychain so that the app login's automatically when it is started, but when I install the TestFlight app over the AppStore app.
The keychain seems to not be the same as the app store because it cannot find the credentials.

both apps have the same bundle identifier.

Comment: for both apps do you use same bundle  identifier?

Comment: yes the have the same bundle identifier

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal. As you install your app from AppStore and from TestFlight, iPhone/iPad consider both the app as different apps even with the same name. 
There may be difference in both builds'versions. Or even if both the builds are same it consider the different one.
 If you have noticed the TestFlight version and AppStore version are installed separately. And another thing to note is that when you install an app from test flight then the app name Start with a **colored Dot** which denotes that the build is downloaded from test flight and it makes the app different from other all apps.
Please see the Image attached which show a build installed from test flight.[Application installed from TestFlight denoted with colored note in the starting of the application name](https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/41/posts/22224/image/figure-testflight-install-3.jpg)

Comment: but it is installed over it, not 2 separate apps.

Comment: Does it contains a colored dot as I have mentioned in my above post?